# Selenium/python 2.7 How to find element that only has a title?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, element

im new to selenium and I am trying to click on an image but when I inspect the element it only has a title, an src=, and an alt=. I would like to use xpath but am unsure exactly how it works on python, on java i would do    `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@title='']"))` but I am unsure of how to do it on python any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, there is the `find_element_by_xpath()` shortcut method:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@title='']")
```

Note that your locator does not look quite reliable. Providing the relevant HTML of the image and its parents might help us to provide you with a better option.